# IP address in ckan.site_url not accepted by ckan db init

Tags: url, dns, ip-address, ckan

I am following the [official installation procedure from package](https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html) for CKAN 2.8 on a Ubuntu 16.04 VM without a domain (reachable via IP address).

I have have configured `/etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini` with the HTTP URL to the VM (`ckan.site_url = http://192.168.56.101:80`) but when I call `ckan db init` it returns the error `ckan.site_url is not configured and it must have a value`. I have also tried other variants for the URL, but none of them worked:

- `http://192.168.56.101`
- `http://192.168.56.101:80`
- `http://192.168.56.101/` ([the docs](https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/maintaining/configuration.html#ckan-site-url) say the trailing slash is not necessary, but you never know)
- `"http://192.168.56.101"`

What am I doing wrong?

You can see below the content of `/etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini` and the output of `ckan db init`.

```sh
daniele@ckantest:~$ cat /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini
solr_url = http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr
ckan.site_id = ckan-demo
ckan.site_url = http://192.168.56.101:80

daniele@ckantest:~$ sudo ckan db init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ckan", line 45, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 236, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 357, in command
    self._load_config(cmd!='upgrade')
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 330, in _load_config
    self.site_user = load_config(self.options.config, load_site_user)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 237, in load_config
    load_environment(conf.global_conf, conf.local_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 116, in load_environment
    p.load_all()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 130, in load_all
    unload_all()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 183, in unload_all
    unload(*reversed(_PLUGINS))
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 211, in unload
    plugins_update()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 122, in plugins_update
    environment.update_config()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 190, in update_config
    'ckan.site_url is not configured and it must have a value.'
RuntimeError: ckan.site_url is not configured and it must have a value. Please amend your .ini file.
```

EDIT:

I added a hostname rule linking `ckan.demo` to `192.168.56.101` and then edited `ckan.ini` using the hostname, but the error persist. Apparently the error is not caused by the IP but by something else.

You can see below the content of `/etc/hosts`, the content of `/etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini` and the output of `ckan db init`.

```sh
daniele@ckantest:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ckantest

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

192.168.56.101 ckan.demo

daniele@ckantest:~$ nmap ckan.demo

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-05 14:26 CEST
Nmap scan report for ckan.demo (192.168.56.101)
Host is up (0.000044s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8800/tcp open  sunwebadmin

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
daniele@ckantest:~$ cat /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini
solr_url = http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr
ckan.site_id = ckan-demo
ckan.site_url = http://ckan.demo
daniele@ckantest:~$ sudo ckan db init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ckan", line 45, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 236, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 357, in command
    self._load_config(cmd!='upgrade')
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 330, in _load_config
    self.site_user = load_config(self.options.config, load_site_user)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 237, in load_config
    load_environment(conf.global_conf, conf.local_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 116, in load_environment
    p.load_all()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 130, in load_all
    unload_all()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 183, in unload_all
    unload(*reversed(_PLUGINS))
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 211, in unload
    plugins_update()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 122, in plugins_update
    environment.update_config()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 190, in update_config
    'ckan.site_url is not configured and it must have a value.'
RuntimeError: ckan.site_url is not configured and it must have a value. Please amend your .ini file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it possible that you forgot to provide the location to the configuration file?

```
ckan -c /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini db init
```

cheers, Florian

Comment: trying the command you suggested ckan throws an error because it does not recognize the '-c' option.

Comment: This is the output:
```
    daniele@ckantest:~$ sudo ckan -c /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini db init
    Usage: ckan [paster_options] COMMAND [command_options]
    
    ckan: error: no such option: -c
    daniele@ckantest:~$ sudo ckan --help
    Usage: ckan [paster_options] COMMAND [command_options]
    
    ckan: error: no such option: -c
    daniele@ckantest:~$ sudo ckan -h
    Usage: ckan [paster_options] COMMAND [command_options]
    
    ckan: error: no such option: -c
```

Comment: I know the `ckan` comand is the way to go now but when i developed for CKAN 2.8 i used the equivalent paster command:

`paster --plugin=ckan db init -c [location to config]`

maybe this works for you

Comment: I solved by running `sudo ckan db init -c /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini`.Ckan threw a different error (`File contains no sections headers`). I searched and found https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/configuration.html#config-file which made me understand both errors: the installation guide is supposed to be for ckan 2.8 and says to edit `/etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini`, but ckan<2.9 searchs by default the config in `/etc/ckan/default/production.ini`. So the installation guide is wrong ing that part. The second error was caused by the ini file not containing the `[app:main]` header.

Comment: So i solved by editing `/etc/ckan/default/production.ini` and running `sudo ckan db init`. Now it throws a password authentication error but it's not related to this issue. Thank you.